# android how have the value of edittext auto format itself and calculate-able at the same time

Tags: android

I have 2 edittexts and 1 textview. 1 edittext for input the price another one the percentage and the textview will display the result of them both `(the price * percentage/100)`  and i want to make the 1st edittext input(for the price) will change the format of the input and display it on the same edittext with decimal format. For example :

```
edittext1
100
```

the user type 100 it will just display 100 ,but when the user type one or more number(S) it will add "," every 3 number

```
edittext1
1,000 
edittext1
10,000 
edittext1
100,000
edittext1
1,000,000
and so on
```

i have the functions, one will autocalculate the value for textview1 , another will convert automatically the input of edittext. However they cant work together because the format for calculation function, it uses int/long/double and for the converter it uses decimalformat . If i use them both the app will crash with `javanumberformatexception`  unable to parse int "1,000"(if we put 1000 into edittext)

my function for autocalculate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {       
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.simulasikredit);

        ethint1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ethint);
        etpersen2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpersen);     
        textvDP1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textvDP);   
etpersen2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                String text1 = ethint1.getText().toString();
                String text2 = etpersen2.getText().toString();
                long input1 = 0;
                long input2 = 0;
                if(text1.length()>0)
                      input1 = Long.valueOf(text1);
                if(text2.length()>0)
                      input2 = Long.valueOf(text2);                
                if (text1.length() != 0) {    
                    long output = (input1 * input2) / 100;
                    textvDP1.setText(""+output);                                     
                }
                else if(text2.length() == 0){                   
                    textvDP1.setText("");
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        }); }
```

et stands for edittext, tv stands for textview

and makedecimal function

```
public void makedecimal(View v)
                {
                                ethint1.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);

                                DigitsKeyListener dkl = new DigitsKeyListener(true,true);
                                ethint1.setKeyListener(dkl);

                                ethint1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
                        private String current = "";

                        @Override
                        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                                String userInput=s.toString();

                                if(!userInput.toString().equals(current)){
                                                ethint1.removeTextChangedListener(this);

                                                String cleanString = userInput.replaceAll("[,]", "");

                                                if(cleanString.length()>0){
                                                                double parsed = Double.parseDouble(cleanString);                                                
                                                                String formated = DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance().format(parsed);

                                                                current = formated;
                                                                ethint1.setText(formated);
                                                                ethint1.setSelection(formated.length());
                                                }else{
                                                                ethint1.setText(cleanString);
                                                                ethint1.setSelection(cleanString.length());
                                                }

                                                ethint1.addTextChangedListener(this);
                    }
```

this makedecimal is `android:onClick` from ethint , ethint is the id(these two come from 1 edittext)

Comment: You might want to create another textview to show their formatted output while they are still typing.

Comment: that's a tricky solution. But my supervisor requested for my app to be able to display like i have explain above. Is there anything you know about making a decimal to string or double/float/int/long? an url or something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I need to fulfil a similar requirements before where we need to format the number in thousands and also support fractions.

My approach is to register a `TextWatcher` format text every time input changed, and provide a public method to get numeric value by stripping separators, which is quite tricky. My solution also caters for locale-specific separator by utilizing [`DecimalFormatSymbols`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) class.

```
private final char GROUPING_SEPARATOR = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getGroupingSeparator();
private final char DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();

...

/**
 * Return numeric value repesented by the text field
 * @return  numeric value or {@link Double.NaN} if not a number
 */
public double getNumericValue() {
    String original = getText().toString().replaceAll(mNumberFilterRegex, "");
    if (hasCustomDecimalSeparator) {
    // swap custom decimal separator with locale one to allow parsing
        original = StringUtils.replace(original,
                String.valueOf(mDecimalSeparator), String.valueOf(DECIMAL_SEPARATOR));
    }

    try {
        return NumberFormat.getInstance().parse(original).doubleValue();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}

/**
 * Add grouping separators to string
 * @param original  original string, may already contains incorrect grouping separators
 * @return  string with correct grouping separators
 */
private String format(final String original) {
    final String[] parts = original.split("\\" + mDecimalSeparator, -1);
    String number = parts[0] // since we split with limit -1 there will always be at least 1 part
            .replaceAll(mNumberFilterRegex, "")
            .replaceFirst(LEADING_ZERO_FILTER_REGEX, "");

    // only add grouping separators for non custom decimal separator
    if (!hasCustomDecimalSeparator) {
        // add grouping separators, need to reverse back and forth since Java regex does not support
        // right to left matching
        number = StringUtils.reverse(
                StringUtils.reverse(number).replaceAll("(.{3})", "$1" + GROUPING_SEPARATOR));
        // remove leading grouping separator if any
        number = StringUtils.removeStart(number, String.valueOf(GROUPING_SEPARATOR));
    }

    // add fraction part if any
    if (parts.length > 1) {
        number += mDecimalSeparator + parts[1];
    }

    return number;
}
```

It's quite tedious to elaborate here so I'll only give a link for your own reading:
https://gist.github.com/hidroh/77ca470bbb8b5b556901

Comment: this is a good reference, since i need "." as separator as in my country currency type. 10000 will be 10.000

Comment: how to use this , i mean StringUtils is another class that will be converted right?, if yes then how to use

Comment: StringUtils is a utility class, part of apache commons-lang3 library. It's quite a big library so check if you want to use it. Otherwise, you can find some smaller library with same functionality. Anyway, the functionalities needed from StringUtils are quite basic, you can also implement by yourself.

Comment: I have published a sample project here, you can try it out as starting point for your integration: https://github.com/hidroh/numeric-edittext

Comment: is there any other way to call the function instead of using custom declaration ? i mean how to use it in a different package/project?

Comment: can u do me a favor? i need your custom edittext but it will not adding floating fraction,  meaning just adding grouping separator